# Issue with System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew() in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am working on Windows 10 UWP app and my requirement is to upload 5 images on the server with unique value. So, I have used `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew()`.Now, when I checked while debugging, I found that randomly sometimes for 2 images, it sends same unique key. Can someone suggest is it better to use System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew()?

All the images are sent using a web service. My sample code for this is following

```
WebServiceUtility serviceUtility = new WebServiceUtility();
List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationToken = cancelSource.Token;
System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask = null;
List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> uploadTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
List<string> uploadedImageIdList = new List<string>();
foreach (var image in _imageCollection)
{
    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        currentTask = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            string imageName = string.Empty;
            string imagePath = string.Empty;
            if (image.IsEvidenceImage)
            {
                imageName = image.EvidencePath.Split('\\')[1];
                imagePath = image.EvidencePath;
            }
            else
            {
                imageName = image.EvidencePath.Split('#')[1].Split('\\')[1];
                imagePath = image.EvidencePath.Split('#')[1];
            }
            byte[] _imageAsByteArray = await GetEvidenceFromIsoStore(imagePath);
            if (null != _imageAsByteArray && _imageAsByteArray.Length > 0)
            {
                IRestResponse response = await serviceUtility.UploadImage
                    (_imageAsByteArray, imageName,
                    new RequestDataGenerator().generateRequestDataForMediaUpload(
                    (null != _imageItem.I_IS_PRIMARY && "1".Equals(_imageItem.I_IS_PRIMARY) ? "1" : "0"),
                    evidenceName
                    ));
                if (response != null && response.RawBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    var successMessage = MCSExtensions.CheckWebserviceResponseCode(response.StatusCode);
                    if (successMessage.Equals(Constants.STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS))
                    {
                        byte[] decryptedevidenceresponse = WebserviceED.finaldecryptedresponse(response.RawBytes);
                        string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedevidenceresponse, 0, decryptedevidenceresponse.Length);
                        JObject reponseObject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                        //Debug.WriteLine("Evidence Upload Response : " + Environment.NewLine);
                        uploadedimageIdList.Add(reponseObject["P_RET_ID"].ToString());
                        try
                        {
                            if (image.IsEvidenceImage)
                            {
                                if (await FileExists(image.EvidencePath))
                                {
                                    StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(image.EvidencePath);
                                    await file.DeleteAsync();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string[] evidenceMedia = image.EvidencePath.Split('#');
                                foreach (string evidenceItem in evidenceMedia)
                                {
                                    if (await FileExists(evidenceItem))
                                    {
                                        StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(evidenceItem);
                                        await file.DeleteAsync();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UserMessageUtil.ShowMessage(successMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
        uploadTasks.Add(currentTask);
    }
}

await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: where and how is the unique key generated?

Comment: It is generated in `generateRequestDataForMediaUpload()`.

Comment: can you paste it, is that method thread safe?

Comment: I have added that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it a separate method:

```
...
foreach (var image in _imageCollection)
{
  if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    currentTask = UploadAsync(...);
    uploadTasks.Add(currentTask);
  }
}
await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);


async Task UploadAsync(...)
{
  string imageName = string.Empty;
  string imagePath = string.Empty;
  ...
}
```

Or, a bit more simply at the call site:

```
...
var uploadTasks = _imageCollection.Select(x => UploadAsync(...));
await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);
```

Comment: Will it not require ' await on currentTask=UploadAsync()'?

Comment: No, because you're just storing the tasks in a list. The `await` happens as part of `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I have one doubt, why you are asking me to make it a different method? Is there any benefit?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: It allows you to avoid the dangerous `ContinueWith` API.

Comment: Ok but i have not used ContinueWith in my code, does it has issue with StartNew()?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: Right, sorry. It allows you to avoid the dangerous `StartNew` API.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. After changing it to different method. I am not facing unique key issues now.